# This strange looking thing was on the leaf, can you identify what this is?

Tags: zoology, entomology, pest-control

[image]I found this today on one of the plant that I grow in the container at home. I cannot identify what kind of insect it is.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is the leaf located in the world?

Answer (score 4):

That is a butterfly chrysalis. Since it is clear, and you can see the wings, it is about to emerge. A chrysalis is the naked pupal stage of a butterfly, as opposed to a "cocoon", which is covered in silk.